# Javascript get URL and post to iFrame not validating

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

This script runs in jsFiddle but not on a browser and does not validate at jsLint.

As a seperate goal, I'd like to post the same URL to n number of iFrames. But that's for another day unless you feel like jumping in on that one!

```
function handleClick() {
    var url = document.getElementById('url_textbox').value;
    document.getElementById('myForm').action = url;
    return true;
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', handleClick, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtpD5/19/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works in jsfiddle is because you have the `onLoad` option set, this will wait for the page to load before your code runs. You will not be able to get the element with id `myForm` unless it is already created. This can be accomplished by putting the js under the element or waiting for the document to load via an event listener.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', handleClick, false);
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtpD5/20/

Comment: Okay, that does make sense but still returning object error / won't run. I do appreciate all the help in here!

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method" Returning on the line you added. I thought this would be a simple little project!